# display sql variable in textbox using php

Tags: php, html, sql

Okay so I am trying to display a forename from one of my customer records on a textbox as I want the user to be able to edit the values of customers stored within the sql database.  I have been trying to do it but can't seem to get it working as it just shows an empty box.  Here is what I am trying to do

```
    <FORM NAME ="form2" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "phptest.php">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="txtForename">Forename:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtForename2" NAME = "txtForename" value = "<?php

 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cardatabase");


$sql = "SELECT forename FROM customers where customerID = 13";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
 echo " $result";



  ?>">
</div>
```

I am trying display it in the value option of the text box but can't seem to get it working.  NOTE: This is for a university project so I am new to this stuff and also I am aware of injection attacks.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggest you [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for the functions you're trying to use. What does `query()` return? Probably not something that can be printed to screen.

Comment: quite possibly, I dunno man im just using the examples we were given but ill go do that

Comment: Just for your reference, even if what you were doing _did_ work, it is incredibly inelegant.  Seeing all of that PHP within an HTML element attribute would make most developers cringe.  If you are being taught to do it this way, you may want to seriously consider a new source of education.

Comment: I remember asking if I can change the value of a textbox with php without doing it through the html textbox value and i got like -10 downvotes from people saying it aint possible.  I agree with you that it is inelegant but I literally only started learning php last week.  I am very used to c#

Comment: And if i do figure it out, I'll work backwards to refine it and even incorporate it into Java functions  to make it more optimised.  I just want to figure out if what im thinking of is possible , sorry it must look awful if you are a qualified programmer

Comment: @JackHenry To be clear, I'm not criticizing _you_.  You said that this is part of a university project.  In my experience, university classes generally involve being taught how to do things, not just told to do something with no learning on the subject-matter beforehand.  If you were given examples showing you to code like this, then I am criticizing your _education_, not you, and I fear what else they may be teaching you.

Comment: Yeah man I know, I wouldn't blame the university, just the particular module I am doing because everything is done through powerpoints.  all the other modules are fine but thanks for your input and all the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cardatabase");
$queryString= "SELECT `forename` FROM `customers` where `customerID` = '13'";
$result =mysqli_query($conn, $queryString);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result ))
    {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result )) {
            $arr[] = $row;

        }
        $forename = $arr[0]['forename'];

    } else {
        $forename = "No data found";
    }

?>
<FORM NAME ="form2" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "phptest.php">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="txtForename">Forename:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtForename2" NAME = "txtForename" value = "<?=$forename?>">
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Nah its fine, you helped out in the end, I am just glad you took the time to help me :)